# Ошибка с анимацией

Tags: wpf, xaml, анимация

Почему у меня программа не хочет компилироваться ? Если в кратце я хочу чтобы при наведении на один rectangle курсором, другой выезжал как-бы, а когда убирает курсор, то rectangle возвращался в исходное положение :

```
  <Rectangle Name="menu" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Canvas.Left="231" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="228" Margin="-237,47,843,0" Panel.ZIndex="5"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF49A2DF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="665">
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="menu">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimation
            From="0"
            To="200"
            Duration="0:0:5"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty
            ="Margin"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimation
            From="200"
            To="0"
            Duration="0:0:5"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty
            ="Margin"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
    </Rectangle>
```

UPD :

```
<Rectangle Name="menu" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Canvas.Left="231" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="228" Margin="-237,47,843,0" Panel.ZIndex="5"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF49A2DF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="665">
            <Rectangle.Style>
                <Style TargetType="menu">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ThicknessAnimation
            From="0"
            To="200"
            Duration="0:0:5"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty
            ="Margin"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ThicknessAnimation
            From="200"
            To="0"
            Duration="0:0:5"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty
            ="Margin"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Rectangle.Style>
        </Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так надо было мне сделать, уже сам додумался :) ...

```
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF49A2DF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="665">
        <Rectangle.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Name="StoryBran">
                            <ThicknessAnimation
                              Storyboard.TargetName="menu"
                              To="0"
                              Duration="0:0:5"
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty ="Margin"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Rectangle.Triggers>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Name="menu" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stroke="Black" Width="222" Margin="-222,0,0,0"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы используете:

> Style TargetType="menu"

Menu не является типом. Это имя Вашего Rectangle.
Правельнее было бы:

```
<Style TargetType="Rectangle">
```

Comment: Не помогло, тему обновил

Comment: В обновленном коде та же ошибка

Comment: после того как я заменил <Style TargetType="menu"> на <Style TargetType="Rectangle"> анимация заработала. По-другому, но прямоугольник вылетает

Comment: Не, я всмысле то что menu должно выезжать а не rectangle в котором Style

Comment: смотрите ответ ниже

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Rectangle Fill="#FF49A2DF" Name="Menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="665">
        <Rectangle.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Name="StoryBran">
                            <DoubleAnimation x:Name="myDoubleAnimation"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
    From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:2" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
    From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:2" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Rectangle.Triggers>
    </Rectangle>
```